# What matrix criteria is "large enough" for Eigen to use a BLAS backend?

Tags: blas, eigen

Eigen's [documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicUsingBlasLapack.html) says that any BLAS back-end can be used (e.g. [MKL](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicUsingIntelMKL.html)) to perform the actual matrix calculations.

It is, however, very vague when discussing the criteria as to which the calculations are offloaded (with added emphasis):

> When doing so, a number of Eigen's algorithms are silently substituted with calls to BLAS or LAPACK routines. These substitutions apply only for Dynamic or **large enough objects** with one of the following four standard scalar types: float, double, complex, and complex. Operations on other scalar types or mixing reals and complexes will continue to use the built-in algorithms.

Unfortunately, there is no further guidance as to what is considered "[large](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=123117) [enough](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=110509#p376921)".

So my questions are:

- What is the criteria to be considered "large enough"
- Does it vary by platform?
- Is this dynamically determined?
- Can it be controlled by the user?

---

**Background:** I have small (25-50 square) matrices, but are large-ish on the embedded platform (Intel Atom Silvermont) we are using. Since this consumes a significant amount of CPU, I am looking to experiment with BLAS back-ends without having to substantially re-write code.

Comment: Does "dynamic" mean size that isn't known at compile-time? This can probably only be answered by looking at Eigen's source, rather than docs, or by attaching a debugger to your code and stepping through it to see what checks it makes.

Comment: @Kirill, Eigen gives the option of either dynamically sized (heap), fixed size (stack), or dynamic with a maximum size (stack). See  [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) for more details.

Comment: Did you get any answer on this?

Comment: @Royi, no such luck.  I guess we will need to dig into the source ...

Comment: Have you tries asking this on Eigen's forum - https://forum.kde.org/viewforum.php?f=74 (Yes, I know, very old forum framework)?

Comment: I am very interested also to get the answer to that question. I cannot find in the sources...